# How do I sort a dictionary by key length, then by an element in the value list?

Tags: python, string, sorting, dictionary

I want to sort a dictionary first by the length of the key and then by one of the elements in my value list.

So far I have gotten close by using lambda sorting, but I run into issues because my values are lists. The documentation isn't clear on how to deal with this (or at least as far as I could see).

```
# What I have so far is:

d = {'ATCG': [1,2,3], 'ATTT':[1,3,5], 'GCT':[2,4,8], 'TCC': [4,5,6], 'AC': 
[7,8,9]}

value_sort = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda item: item[0]) 
# this only sorts by the first item in my list-- how do I sort by 
the third item in my list?

key_sort = sorted(value_sort, key=len, reverse=True) 
# sorts by largest length key

for k in key_sort:
     v = d[k[0]]
     print(k[0) + ":" + str(v))
```

What I want the output to look like is:

```
ATCG:[1,2,3]
ATTT:[1,3,5]
TCC:[4,5,6]
GCT:[2,4,8]
AC:[7,8,9]
```

Where the sort is by largest key, then by smallest third value in my value list.

Edit: I made the keys more clear

Comment: I edited it for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be easier to prepare your key function if you break it out as its own function instead of using a lambda.

Also you may want to use `OrderedDict` to maintain the order after it's sorted:

```py
from collections import OrderedDict

def get_keylength(v):
    key, values = v
    return len(key), values[0]

d = {'ATCG': [1,2,3], 'ATTT':[1,3,5], 'GCT':[2,4,8], 'TCC': [4,5,6], 'AC': [7,8,9]}
od = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=get_keylength, reverse=True))
```

> OrderedDict([('ATCG', [1, 2, 3]), ('ATTT', [1, 3, 5]), ('TCC', [4, 5, 6]), ('GCT', [2, 4, 8]), ('AC', [7, 8, 9])])

If you want cleaner output you can use `pprint` (pretty print):

```py
import pprint
pprint.pprint(od)
OrderedDict([('ATCG', [1, 2, 3]),
             ('ATTT', [1, 3, 5]),
             ('TCC', [4, 5, 6]),
             ('GCT', [2, 4, 8]),
             ('AC', [7, 8, 9])])

# To get rid of OrderedDict you can convert back to a standard dictionary with `dict()`
pprint.pprint(dict(od))
{'AC': [7, 8, 9],
 'ATCG': [1, 2, 3],
 'ATTT': [1, 3, 5],
 'GCT': [2, 4, 8],
 'TCC': [4, 5, 6]}
```

Comment: How do I print ordered dictionaries out nicely like I did in my output example?

Comment: you can use `pprint`, or print useing od.items()

Comment: If you're using CPython 3.6+, regular dicts are ordered.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of sorting a dictionary by length of values then by values

Example 1:

```
d = {'ATCG':[1,2,3], 'ATTT':[1,3,5], 'TCC':[4,5,6], 'GCT':[2,4,8], 'AC':[7,8,9]}
# Use tuple to specify multiple criteria to sort upon
# i.e. first by length, then by key length, 
# then value (i.e. t[0] is key, t[1] is value)
value_sort = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: (len(t[0]), t[1]))

for k, v in value_sort:
  print(k, v)
```

Output

```
AC [7, 8, 9]
GCT [2, 4, 8]
TCC [4, 5, 6]
ATCG [1, 2, 3]
ATTT [1, 3, 5]
```

Example 2:

```
d = {"one": [(1,3),(1,4)], 
        "two": [(1,2),(1,2),(1,3)], 
        "three": [(1,1)]}

# Use tuple to specify multiple criteria to sort upon
# i.e. first by length, then by value
# t[1] is value of dictionary entry
value_sort = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: (len(t[1]), t[1]))

for k, v in value_sort:
  print(k, v)
```

Output

```
three [(1, 1)]
one [(1, 3), (1, 4)]
two [(1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 3)]
```

Comment: I need it sorted by the length of the key first, then by the value of the last element in my list.